# How can I customize rails3 validation error?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a text input name 'email', and if I set :message => 'Your email is wrong kind' the validation error message will have something like

'Email Your email is wrong kind.'

I am wondering if there is any way to remove that orginal input name (in above case, its Email) from the validation error output in rails3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this, please let me know what it is, but this will work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate do |user|
    user.errors.add_to_base("Your email is of the wrong kind") unless user.email =~ email_regexp
  end
end
```

An other hack-ish way to do this is to define a custom translation

```
# en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "Your email"
```

Combine this with `:message => 'is wrong kind'` and it should work. (although it's not really valid english ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define your messages default format at you YAML file like this:

en:
  # Active Model
  errors:
    # The default format to use in full error messages.
    format: "%{attribute} %{message}"

Just remove the attribute part of the format.